# Flutter change background of selected tab

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I created a new navigation bar on the bottom of the screen. I want to change the Background of the Tab I am in when its clicked. How do I change it? I can't get it working. I only got it to change the label color or icon color with "activeIcon". What does @override do?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'Neu.dart';
import 'Beliebt.dart';
import 'Profil.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    NeuPage(),
    BeliebtPage(),
    ProfilPage(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
            title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                  Image.asset(
                 'assets/logo_straight.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  height: 32,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),


        body: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          currentIndex: _selectedTab,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedTab = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.quoteRight, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Neu', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Beliebt', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Profil', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to you items array to something like this:

```
  items:  [
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.quoteRight, color: Colors.white),
    title: Text(
      'Neu',
      style:
          TextStyle(color: _selectedTab == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
    )),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.white),
    title: Text(
      'Beliebt',
      style:
          TextStyle(color: _selectedTab == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
    )),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.white),
    title: Text(
      'Profil',
      style:
          TextStyle(color: _selectedTab == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
    )),],
```

Comment: Thx, but I dont want the text to change. I just want to have (in this example an orange normal background for the navbar. With white texts and icons. When I tap on one of the 3 icons. I want the background collor of the tab I clicked in the navbar to be darker or something

Comment: Hey @MikaCmn, you could post a screenshot so we know what exactly you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build your own custom Widgets.
This is what Flutter is made for. You can build everything as you want it.
You will achieve to be fluent on doing this by exercise. I made a MVE for you to check out. There is much to be done better and smoother, but I think for a beginner it is good to see the detailed implementation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    Container(child: Center(child: Text('1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),)),),
    Container(child: Center(child: Text('2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),)),),
    Container(child: Center(child: Text('3 ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),)),),
  ];


  _changePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (index >= _pageOptions.length){
        return;
      }
      _selectedTab = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
            title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/logo_straight.png',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                height: 32,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),


        body: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        BottomNavItem(
                          iconData: Icons.add,
                          title: 'Add',
                          selected: _selectedTab == 0,
                          onTap: (){
                            _changePage(0);
                          },
                        ),
                        BottomNavItem(
                          iconData: Icons.add,
                          title: 'Add',
                          selected: _selectedTab == 1,
                          onTap: (){
                            _changePage(1);
                          },
                        ),
                        BottomNavItem(
                          iconData: Icons.add,
                          title: 'Add',
                          selected: _selectedTab == 2,
                          onTap: (){
                            _changePage(2);
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final IconData iconData;
  final String title;
  final bool selected;
  final Function onTap;

  BottomNavItem({this.iconData, this.title, this.selected, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: InkWell(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            color: selected ? Colors.orange : Colors.orangeAccent,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(iconData),
                Text(title)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: onTap,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution for you as new to flutter but nevertheless you should think about building your own widget in the future 
here and exmple i wrap your items inside a container and GestureDetector the container get same size of your items and the default background color and at everyclick you change the container color and reset other items color which are variables u declare above

```
GestureDetector(onTap => {firstItemColor = newColor , seconditem = oldColor } ,child: Container(Color: firstItemColor ,height: itemHeight , width: itemWidth,
    child:BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.white),
        title: Text(
          'Beliebt',
          style:
              TextStyle(color: _selectedTab == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
        )))),
```